# Does something like ".net reflector" exist for objective-c applications?

Tags: objective-c

For .NET applications a special tool called .NET Reflector exist that can load a compiled application and show a list of classes, imports, reversed code and other app "internals". Objective-c with Cocoa is dynamic like .NET - it stores type and class information inside compiled app so selectors can be accessed by name etc.

So, is there some tool like .NET Reflector but for objective-c code so i can load compiled objective-c application and get list of classes, interfaces, selectors etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is. It's called `class-dump` and is available [here.](http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a freeware called ilspy.net, can be found [here](http://ilspy.net/)

Comment: ILSpy can't deal with Objective-C.